# A puzzled MySQL deadlock caused by two update..in

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, database-deadlocks

We got a puzzled deadlock on MySQL 5.7 (Engine: InnoDB, Isolation Level: RR). The report result of `show engine innodb status` as below shown

```
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1739954050, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 4 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 4253877, OS thread handle 47904135608064, query id 4259685238 jacky Searching rows for update

        UPDATE fruit_setting set
        value = CASE
            WHEN eid = 'L1XSHY' and `key` = 'priority' THEN '14343'
            WHEN eid = 'Rtb95t' and `key` = 'priority' THEN '14344'
            WHEN eid = 'wdsNwr' and `key` = 'priority' THEN '14345'           
            WHEN eid = 'K1Ikqy' and `key` = 'priority' THEN '14345'
            WHEN eid = 
            
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 533 page no 65378 n bits 0 index PRIMARY of table `jacky`.`fruit_setting` trx id 1739954050 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
...


*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1739954049, ACTIVE 0 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 94 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 184 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 4257460, OS thread handle 47904340621056, query id 4259685231  jacky Searching rows for update

        UPDATE fruit_setting set value = CASE
            WHEN eid = 'M5ecaA' and `key` = 'priority' THEN '16171'
            WHEN eid = '1o0bdT' and `key` = 'priority' THEN '16172'
            WHEN eid = 'XNxx5S' and `key` = 'priority' THEN '16173'
            WHEN eid = '1o0bdT' and `key` = 'priority' THEN '16174'
            WHEN eid = 
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 533 page no 65378 n bits 0 index PRIMARY of table `jacky`.`fruit_setting` trx id 1739954049 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 105 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
 ...

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 533 page no 46944 n bits 0 index PRIMARY of table `jacky`.`fruit_setting` trx id 1739954049 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 58 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 10; compact format; info bits 0
...
```

The sqls in above report has been truncated (might due to size limit of MySQL), one of the whole sql looks like (we only record the prepared statement)

```
UPDATE fruit_setting set value = CASE
            WHEN eid = ? and `key` = ? THEN ?
            WHEN eid = ? and `key` = ? THEN ?
            WHEN eid = ? and `key` = ? THEN ?
            WHEN eid = ? and `key` = ? THEN ?
            WHEN eid = ? and `key` = ? THEN ?
            WHEN eid = ? and `key` = ? THEN ?
            WHEN eid = ? and `key` = ? THEN ?
            WHEN eid = ? and `key` = ? THEN ?
            WHEN eid = ? and `key` = ? THEN ?
        END
WHERE aid = ? and eid in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `key` = ?
```

The table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `fruit_setting` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `aid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `eid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `i_eid_key` (`eid`, `key`),
  KEY `i_aid_key` (`aid`, `key`),
  KEY `i_aid_eid` (`aid`, `eid`)
);
```

Note that the `aid` and `key` in two sqls are the same and the `eid` in **in** clause could be overlapped; And thus we guess that the deadlock occurred since the locks are acquired in reverse order on index `i_eid_key` or `i_aid_eid`.

**Question 1**: why the lock is not waiting/hold on secondary index **i_eid_key** or **i_aid_eid**, but on primary index? AFAIK, the secondary index would be locked before primary index if the searching for update used the secondary index.

> If a secondary index is used in a search and index record locks to be set are exclusive, InnoDB also retrieves the corresponding clustered index records and sets locks on them.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

**Question 2**: Does MySQL acquire lock on index record one by one based on the order of **eid** appeared in **in** clause during execute `update ... where eid in (...)`?

By the way, the deadlock is hard to reproduce, I have tried to locked on `eid` in different order, however, the new deadlock report showed that the lock was on the secondary index.

Comment: Not related to your question — but don't put your `?` placeholders inside quotes. Then they are not parameter placeholders anymore, they're just literal strings that happen to be `'?'`.

Comment: Does this table have a secondary UNIQUE KEY? The lock acquisition of an index should be atomic, i.e. not row by row. But I've seen cases where locks on a table's second UNIQUE KEY are _not_ acquired simultaneously with locks on the primary key. There seems to be a race condition, and two queries can get into a deadlock that way. Example: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86812

Comment: Yes, there is a secondary unique key and a PK. The lock acquisition on an index record should be atomic, but since there are multiple eid in in clause, I guess the whole is not atomic.

Comment: Right. In these cases, I've told the developers at my company they have options: (1) remove the secondary unique key (or else remove the primary key and make the former unique key into the primary key), (2) use `LOCK TABLES` to make each thread acquire an atomic table-lock before updating the table, or (3) run the updates from a single application thread by using a critical section or something. Final option: deal with the deadlocks by handling exceptions in the app and re-trying updates.

Comment: I think the case in https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86812 is different from mine.  The deadlock in 86812 is because the session 2 hold S mode lock on secondary unique index record after the delete in session 1, and thus the latter insert in session 1 triggers the deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

**For Question 1:**

After some discussion and thought, we think that the deadlock might occurred like this: There are at least two same `extension_ids` in two sqls.

1. InnoDB first locks on two different secondary indexes, such as `i_eid_key`  `i_aid_key`
2. and then lock the PK record, which is in the reverse order, and finally result in the deadlock.

[image: Deadlock]

**For Question 2**:

The MySQL optimization would sort the (constant) values in `in clause`